# Finding Most Frequent Element(s) In A File Of Integers

Tags: java

I am working on a program to find the most frequent element(s) in a text file. Thus far I have made the file read into a List then iterate through the list to find the occurrences of every value and map them in a SortedMap.

The issue is occurring with files where every digit occurs equally. My Map is not filling with all the data and will only contain one of the digits at the end.

Here is my code:

```
public class FileAnalyzer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

    System.out.print("Please Enter A File Name: ");
    String file = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    SortedMap<Integer, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>();    
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
    }

    Collections.sort(numbers);

    int frequency = 0;
    int tempNum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        if (tempNum == numbers.get(i)) {
            frequency++;
        } else {
            if (frequency != 0) {
                sortedMap.put((frequency+1), tempNum);
            }
            frequency = 0;
            tempNum = numbers.get(i);
        }
    }
     if (frequency !=0) {
        sortedMap.put((frequency+1), tempNum);
    }

    final long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

        System.out.println(sortedMap);      
        System.out.println("Runtime: " + duration + " ms\n");       
        System.out.println("Least Frequent Digit(s): " + sortedMap.get(sortedMap.firstKey()) + "\nOccurences: " + sortedMap.firstKey());        
    }
}
```

Also this is the text file I am running into issues when reading from:

```
1
2
1
1
2
1
1
2
1
2
2
2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you learn when you ran it through a debugger?

Comment: What are you getting as the result?

Comment: @TheCrzyMan With the given file the SortedMap will contain `{6=2}`

Comment: Also, you could probably optimize your code by populating a map<integer, integer> as you read in the file. Just set the count to one if the key doesn't exist yet, and increment it if it already exists. Then run through and keep track of which key has the highest number

Answer (score 0):

You should look up the [Java Documentation for TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#put-K-V-). It is designed to not store duplicate keys, so since you are sorting on frequency as a key, values with the same frequency will be overwritten in your map!